# Debugging an Eclipse + Kotlin + Gradle project?

Tags: eclipse, gradle, kotlin

How does one debug an Eclipse + Kotlin + Gradle project? I would assume a debug configuration for Kotlin application would have to be created in Eclipse but I don't see anything Kotlin related in the Menu > Debug > Debug Configurations.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to have the Kotlin perspective and you need to right click on the Kotlin class you want to debug, not the project